# Ignore ssl certification MKNetworkKit

Tags: ios, mknetworkkit

So it seems that ASIHTTPRequest allows you to ignore the certificates on https:// endpoints. I'm currently using MKNetworkKit and have implemented all my calls. Unfortunately, our testing server is on https but does not have a SSL certificate.

I'm able to connect fine using a curl with the -k command. I've tried various things in MKNetworkKit to ignore the NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, but to no avail. The latest thing I tried was the following:

```
op.authHandler = ^(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge)
{
    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:_userName password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
};
```

This allowed me to actually get a 401 error returned (instead of being blank). Looking at the curl string, MKNetworkKit strips my username/password when the above block hits. I'm not sure if that's progress or not.

Anyone know how to simply ignore the SSL certificate?

Edit:

I had to update MKNetwork kit to get the new method `ShouldContinueWithInvalidCertificate` on `MKNetworkOperation` and my testing server got the certError fixed.

However, now I'm having a weird error happening. I'm still unable to get any return from two specific endpoints on the server. I look at the request, copy it into the command as a curl, and it immediately returns results. I'm not getting an error either from the operation.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MKNetworkOperation` class has a property called `shouldContinueWithInvalidCertificate` which is defaulted to NO. All you have to do is set it to YES, and it will ignore the certs.

The comments:

```
/*!
 *  @abstract Boolean variable that states whether the operation should continue if the certificate is invalid.
 *  @property shouldContinueWithInvalidCertificate
 *
 *  @discussion
 *  If you set this property to YES, the operation will continue as if the certificate was valid (if you use Server Trust Auth)
 *  The default value is NO. MKNetworkKit will not run an operation with a server that is not trusted.
 */
```

Comment: Interesting - looks like I was using a version where this wasn't available. I've updated and tried using it, but it still fails to connect to the api endpoint. What's bizarre is it returns absolutely no data, but doesn't have an error. When I run the curl equivalent request generated by MKNetworkKit, I get an ssl error (since the server doesn't have a certificate). When I put the -k in, I get valid return. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm. I recommended you enable debugging:
#define DEBUG 1

Comment: The heavy lifting happens in: 
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
Of MKNetworkOperation

Comment: So I found out that there was a bug within MKNetworkOperation itself. If I swapped my operations, then the ones that were working would stop working and the ones that weren't now worked. I think it was because I was declaring my `op` as __weak, then running four of those calls in parallel. By dropping the __weak declaration of `op`, it solved the issue. I'm marking your response as the answer, since you did solve the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. Were you adding the __weak declaration of `op` in your method or were they class props?

Comment: I was adding the __weak declaration of op in the method. It was `MKNetworkOperation *_op = [sharedEngine getDocuments]; __weak MKNetworkOperation *op=_op;`. While running these in parallel though, I had 4 different `op` declared. Was really to finally figure it out.